# How do I dynamically create FMOD::Sounds when constructor is private?

Tags: c++, audio, fmod

I'd like to have a C++ vector (or NSMutableDictionary) of sounds, so the user can record N things and play them back.

However when I try to create a `new FMOD::Sound` I get told its constructor is private - in the `Sound` class definition it states:

> Constructor made private so user cannot statically instance a Sound class.  Appropriate Sound creation or retrieval function must be used.

So how do I dynamically create a new sound object? There's a createSound method in system, but it requires an existing Sound object reference to be passed in to it:

`FMOD_RESULT createSound (const char *name_or_data, FMOD_MODE mode, FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO *exinfo, Sound **sound);`

Comment: Looks like the function wants you to pass in the the address of a pointer: `Sound* newSound = nullptr; createSound (..., &newSound);`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to πάντα ῥεῖ for the answer to this. You just have to create a null pointer of type `Sound` and then call `createSound(...)` with that:

```
Sound* newSound = nullptr;
createSound (..., &newSound);
```